# TV app home screen on iOS and Apple TV not working

Tags: ios, icloud, appletv

So the TV app in iOS and Apple TV, where you setup your favorite shows in a carousel isn’t working. When I open it up on iOS or iPad or Apple TV, the first tab shows the scrolling circle and nothing appears.
[image]

The other tabs work. Now my iCloud account is logged in and podcast, App Store and everything else seems to work. I’ve restarted my phone, logged out and in of iCloud, and reset network. I have no idea what else I can do.

I basically want to see my HBO and other shows that are personalized according to my viewing.

Comment: I would have suggested logging out of the TV app, but that can only be done (in iOS at least) by clicking on your picture/icon in the upper right of that Watch Now screen.  But, that's not loading for you at all, so deleting the app might be the best approach, as "P L" suggested.  Or borrow a friend's Mac and log in and try the TV app there.  You just might need to clear some bad iCloud data, since it's happening on more than 1 device for you.  If it's still stuck on the Mac, then your iCloud data is corrupted somehow and you might need Apple to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the TV app and download it again. It often helps as it clears the cache files and sometimes even takes care of these kind of bugs and even app crashes. It’s not ideal but it often works.